# What do you call different formations of polycyclic molecules, such as the 'bent' phenanthrene vs. the 'linear' anthracene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, hydrocarbons

Are there terms, IUPAC or not, that describe multiple carbon rings fused in different shapes, like the aforementioned anthracene and phenanthrene?

Also, I thought I read about a term describing carbon rings that only attach at one carbon, as opposed to two....

Comment: Anthracene and phenanthrene are isomers. I am not aware of a more specifiс term, though it might  exist. Rings with one common atom are called [spiro compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiro_compound) (as in "spiral"; that's not somebody's name).

Comment: You could say *which type* of isomer they are, so constitution isomer would be somewhat more specific. But I‘m not aware of something more specific than that, either.

Comment: Naphthalene, Phenanthrene, Anthracene all are "fused"-Bicyclo/Tricyclo rings

Comment: The answer to the final line is: spiro.